# Bootstrap: How can you have a top menu change (ie. change with CSS from transparent to opaque) when you scroll past a certain point in the page?

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have a top menu using Bootstrap and have made it transparent, but want it to change to opaque once a user scrolls to the next section/div on the page. Anyone know the best/easiest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class on scroll down, or remove your class what is rewriting Bootstrap styles.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        // Transition effect for navbar 
        $(window).scroll(function() {
          // checks if window is scrolled more than 500px, adds/removes solid class
          if($(this).scrollTop() > 500) { 
              $('.navbar').addClass('solid');
          } else {
              $('.navbar').removeClass('solid');
          }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will assign a class to your top menu initially setting it to a transparent version, then once you scroll down past the threshold, it will remove that class which will remove the transparency.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollPercent = ($(window).scrollTop() / $(document).outerHeight()) * 100;
  if (scrollPercent > 20)
    $('#container').removeClass('transparent')
  else
    $('#container').addClass('transparent')
});
```

```css
#container {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: orange;
}

.transparent {
  opacity: .2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container" class="transparent">
</div>
```